# When will/won't Python suspend execution of a coroutine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

When I run it on cpython 3.6, the following program prints `hello world` a single time and then spins forever.

As a side note, uncommenting the `await asyncio.sleep(0)` line causes it to print `hello world` every second, which is understandable.

```
import asyncio

async def do_nothing():
    # await asyncio.sleep(0)
    pass

async def hog_the_event_loop():
    while True:
        await do_nothing()

async def timer_print():
    while True:
        print("hello world")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(timer_print())
loop.create_task(hog_the_event_loop())
loop.run_forever()
```

This behavior (printing `hello world` a single time) makes sense to me, because `hog_the_event_loop` never blocks and therefore has no need to suspend execution. **Can I rely on this behavior?** When the line `await do_nothing()` runs, is it possible that rather than entering the `do_nothing()` coroutine, execution will actually suspend and resume `timer_print()`, causing the program to print `hello world` a second time?

Put more generally: When will python suspend execution of a coroutine and switch to another one? Is it potentially on *any* use of the `await` keyword? or is it only in cases where this results in an underlying `select` call (such as I/O, sleep timers, etc)?

### Additional Clarification

I understand that if `hog_the_event_loop` looked like this, it would certainly never yield execution to another coroutine:

```
async def hog_the_event_loop():
    while True:
        pass
```

I'm trying to specifically get at the question of whether `await do_nothing()` is any different than the above.

Comment: Without the `await` line your `hog_the_event_loop` has only synchronous code in an endless loop. That will block the event loop. With the line on every iteration an `await` will be reached and the event loop can leave the corouting and execute an other waiting task.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure I understand: the mere use of `await` in `await do_nothing()` doesn't qualify as asynchronous code, and it won't be sufficient to cause another task to execute, as `await asyncio.sleep(0)` would?

Comment: There has to be something awaitable involved.

Comment: I see. But getting at this edge case, does `await do_nothing()` count as being cooperative? since it is indeed using the `await` keyword?

Comment: Some context that I sort of remember from David Beazley (but details are fuzzy, so I'll leave a comment rather than answer): the `async/await` model is an example of cooperative multitasking: a function is implemented in a manner to signal the points in the function's execution when it is appropriate or useful to yield control back to the event loop; and the function uses `await` to send that signal. A function without `await` is not being "cooperative", so to speak.

Comment: Regarding your follow-up, `await do_nothing()` establishes the expectation that `do_nothing()` will also participate in the cooperative regime. Since it doesn't, the endless loop in `hog_the_event_loop()` never gives up control. That at least is my intuitive understanding of this; it's been a while since I spent a lot of time with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This behavior (printing hello world a single time) makes sense to me, because `hog_the_event_loop` never blocks and therefore has no need to suspend execution. **Can I rely on this behavior?**

Yes. This behavior directly follows from how `await` is both specified and implemented by the language. Changing it to suspend without the awaitable object having itself suspended would certainly be a breaking change, both for asyncio [and](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio) [other](https://github.com/python-trio/trio) Python libraries based in async/await.

> Put more generally: When will python suspend execution of a coroutine and switch to another one? Is it potentially on any use of the `await` keyword?

From the caller's perspective, any `await` can *potentially* suspend, at the discretion of the awaited object, also known as an [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables). So the final decision of whether a particular `await` will suspend is on the awaitable (or on awaitables it awaits itself if it's a coroutine, and so on). Awaiting an awaitable that doesn't choose to suspend is the same as running ordinary Python code - it won't pass control to the event loop.

The leaf awaitables that actually suspend are typically related to IO readiness or timeout events, but not always. For example, awaiting a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) item will suspend if the queue is empty, and awaiting [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) will suspend until the function running in the other thread completes.

It is worth mentioning that `asyncio.sleep` is [explicitly guaranteed](https://bugs.python.org/issue34476) to suspend execution and defer to the event loop, even when the specified delay is 0 (in which case it will immediately resume on the next event loop pass).

Answer (score 3):

No, `await do_nothing()` will never suspend.  `await` **propagates** suspension from an awaitable by suspending the surrounding coroutine in response.  But when the awaitable is already ready, there’s nothing to wait for and execution continues from the `await` (with a return value, in general).  A nother way of thinking about “nothing to wait for” is that the event loop literally has **no object** on which to base the timing of resuming from a notional suspension; even “resume as soon as other pending tasks suspend” is a schedule that would have to be expressed as some object (*e.g.*, `sleep(0)`).

A coroutine that does nothing is always ready, just like one that sleeps is ready after the time elapses.  Put differently, a coroutine that just sleeps *N* times suspends *N* times—even if *N* is 0.